# Power Query Output Table Date Formatting Inconsistency

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-tables

I have a Power Query which collects data from a .txt file and after some transforming I output it onto worksheet.

All formatting is done well and it always worked well until recently, when I noticed that the formatting of dates is correct only until certain row and then it continues as general (where it shows the number of days that passed since 01/01/1900). Please refer to the snippet below.

Do you know what could be the reason? I don't load this particular query to Data Model (it sometimes causes some weird behavior of the table, like sorting issues).
[image]

Comment: What’s the column type in power query?

Comment: that likely has something to do with a formatting issue in Excel. Somehow a row got added without the date formatting, and the table copied it down. Try copying the format of a correctly formatted table cell down to the end of the column. Then do a refresh and see if it "holds".

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, the formatting in power query is Date (or Date / Time in some cases)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I've been thinking the same and I did apply correct formatting through whole columns, but after refreshing the query the issue re-appeared..

Comment: Try setting up a new query.  Probably easiest to do this by copying the M-Code to a text file, deleting the existing query, then create a new one and paste the M-Code back in.  That should create a new Output Table.